# Убрать одинаковые значения в массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Вот есть такой массив $actualPostsIdArr

```
Array
(
    [0] => Реклама,Мультфильм
    [1] => Обучение, Инструкция
    [2] => Инструкция
    [3] => Инструкция
)
```

Делаю так

```
$actualPostsIdArrUnique = array_unique($actualPostsIdArr);
```

Что выводит

```
Array
(
    [0] => Реклама,Мультфильм
    [1] => Обучение, Инструкция
    [2] => Инструкция
)
```

Нужно получить ['Реклама','Мультфильм','Обучение','Инструкция']; Как это сделать средствами php ?

Comment: Разбить каждый элемент по запятой и уже потом array_unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array_reduce($actualPostsIdArr, function($carry, $item) {
    return array_merge(
        $carry,
        array_map('trim', explode(',', $item))
    );
}, []);
$result = array_unique($result);
```

То же самое с пояснениями

```
// Для каждого элемента из массива выполняем функцию, которая:
//                            ↓                 ↓
$result = array_reduce($actualPostsIdArr, function($carry, $item) {
            
    $arr1 = explode(',', $item);       // 1. Разбивает строку на массив строк,
                                       //    используя в качестве разделителя ','

    $arr2 = array_map('trim', $arr1);  // 2. Для каждой строки в получившемся массиве $arr1 
                                       //    вызывает функцию trim(), которая удаляет пробелы
                                       //    из начала и конца строки
            
    return array_merge($carry, $arr2); // 3. Объединяет получившийся массив $arr2 с массивом $carry,
                                       //    полученном на предыдущей итерации
}, []);

$result = array_unique($result);       // убирает повторяющиеся значения из массива
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr =
[
    'Реклама, Мультфильм',
    'Обучение, Инструкция',
    'Инструкция',
    'Инструкция'
];
$emtyArr=[];
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
    if(count(explode(',',$arr[$i]))>1){
        array_push($emtyArr,trim(explode(',',$arr[$i])[0]));
        array_push($emtyArr,trim(explode(',',$arr[$i])[1]));
    }else{
        array_push($emtyArr,trim($arr[$i]));
    }
}
print_r(array_unique($emtyArr));
```

Если я вас правильно понял, то вот. Функция `trim` используется для удаления пробелов из начала и концы строки. Так как у вас после запятой стоят пробелы, то array_unique будет воспринимать " Инструкция" и "Инструкция", и дабы этого избежать пришлось прибегнуть к ней.