# Сделать выборку по двум массивам

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив
$idFiltersArr

```
Array
(
    [248] => Реклама,Мультфильм
    [244] => Обучение, Инструкция
    [241] => Инструкция
    [234] => Инструкция
)
```

И массив $filtersArr

```
Array
(
    [0] => Инструкция
)
```

Вот код выборки

```
    foreach ($idFiltersArr as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($filtersArr as $filterskey => $filtersvalue) {
            if($value == $filtersvalue) {
                array_push($resPostsId, $key);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

print_r($resPostsId);
```

Получаю такой массив

```
Array
(
    [0] => 241
    [1] => 234
)
```

А нужно

```
Array
(
    [0] => 244
    [1] => 241
    [2] => 234
)
```

Как это сделать? Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Убрать одинаковые значения в массиве](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1148401/%d0%a3%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы ставите условием жесткое равенство значений:

```
if($value == $filtersvalue) {
```

тогда как в Вашем случае необходимо искать подстроку в строке. Для этого можно использовать `strpos()` или `stripos()`:

```
if( stripos($value, $filtersvalue) !== false) { ... }
```